# Rails migration giving error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, rails-migrations

I created a model called customer. The migrate file is as follows:-

```
class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
        create_table :customers , :primary_key => :customer_id , do |t|
          t.integer :customer_id
          t.string :first_name
          t.string :last_name
          t.string :address_1
          t.string :address_2
          t.string :city
          t.string :state
          t.bigint :postal_code

          t.timestamps
        end
  end
end
```

Now when I run rails db:migrate, this is the error that I get:-

```
rails aborted!
SyntaxError: /home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/db/migrate/20170428100848_create_customers.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block
imary_key => :customer_id , do |t|
                              ^
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/db/migrate/20170428100848_create_customers.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_end
          t.integer :customer_id
                     ^
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/db/migrate/20170428100848_create_customers.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The schema.rb file has no sign of the customer table either. Can someone help?
EDIT:
After removing the comma after customer_id I'm getting these:-

```
== 20170428100848 CreateCustomers: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:customers, {:primary_key=>:customer_id})
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

you can't redefine the primary key column 'customer_id'. To define a custom primary key, pass { id: false } to create_table.
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/db/migrate/20170428100848_create_customers.rb:4:in `block in change'
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/db/migrate/20170428100848_create_customers.rb:3:in `change'
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
ArgumentError: you can't redefine the primary key column 'customer_id'. To define a custom primary key, pass { id: false } to create_table.
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/db/migrate/20170428100848_create_customers.rb:4:in `block in change'
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/db/migrate/20170428100848_create_customers.rb:3:in `change'
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: I have added the steps to change primary key for a model

Answer (score 1):

Remove `,` from below line:

```
create_table :customers , :primary_key => :customer_id , do |t|
```

correct is:

```
create_table :customers , :primary_key => :customer_id do |t|
```

Code to set primary key:

```
 create_table(:my_table, :primary_key => 'userID') do |t|
   # Primary key column will be created automatically
   # Do not create here
   # t.column :userID, :integer, :null => false
   ...
 end
```

Comment: I'm getting some other error. I've pasted the code after the 'EDIT' portion

Comment: @sindhugauri do rake db:rollback then run rake db:migrate

Comment: @sindhugauri check my updated post to set primary key

Comment: @sindhugauri accept my answer if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: have you done this: create_table :customers, id: false do |t|

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `,` at the end of line:3

Change this line

```
create_table :customers , :primary_key => :customer_id , do |t|
```

to

```
create_table :customers , :primary_key => :customer_id do |t|
```

You can check for the syntax and other options [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

**EDIT**

For the second error remove the `:primary_key => :customer_id` from migration

```
class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :customers, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :customer_id
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :address_1
      t.string :address_2
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.bigint :postal_code

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and specify primary key in model

```
class Customer
  self.primary_key = :customer_id
end
```

Comment: It says `SQLite3::SQLException: table "customers" already exists: CREATE TABLE "customers" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "customer_id" integer, "first_name" varchar, "last_name" varchar, "address_1" varchar, "address_2" varchar, "city" varchar, "state" varchar, "postal_code" bigint, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)
`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last comma on the third line:

```
create_table :customers , :primary_key => :customer_id do |t|
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
        create_table :customers , :id => :false do |t|
          t.integer :customer_id, primary: true
          t.string :first_name
          t.string :last_name
          t.string :address_1
          t.string :address_2
          t.string :city
          t.string :state
          t.bigint :postal_code

          t.timestamps
        end
  end
end
```